# sql multiple date group by aggregations

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I have an sql table called components that looks something like this

```
id    component_id    date_updated     status
--    ------------    ------------     ------
1     1               2019-08-02       EDIT
2     1               2019-08-01       PUBLISH
3     2               2019-08-12       PUBLISH
4     3               2019-08-07       EDIT
5     3               2019-08-06       EDIT
6     1               2019-06-01       EDIT
```

now what i want is a new table to see when last updated and when last published and the publish state (i have several in production)

```
component_id     last_updated    last_status     last_published   published_status
------------     ------------    -----------     --------------   ----------------

1                2019-08-02      EDIT            2019-08-01      PUBLISH
2                2019-08-12      PUBLISH         2019-08-12      PUBLISH
3                2019-08-07      EDIT            <BLANK>
```

I started off like this

```
select c1.component_id, c1.date_updated as last_updated, c2.status 
from (
     select component_id, max(date_updated) 
     from components
     group_by component_id) as c1
left join components as c2 on c1.component_id = c2.component_id
```

but then i kinda got stuck and complicated things when i wanted to get the next date_updated when status = 'PUBLISH'

any direction on how i should do this? Its for a postgres database

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation for the two date columns and then arrays for the last status:

```
select component_id,
       max(date_updated) as last_updated,
       (array_agg(status order by date_updated))[1] as last_status,
       max(date_updated) filter (where status = 'published') as last_published,
       max(status) filter (where status = 'published') as last_published_status
from components
group by component_id;
```

Using `array_agg()` like this is equivalent to a `first()` aggregation function.

There are other ways to approach this without subqueries, for instance, using `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (component_id) component_id,
       date_updated as last_updated,
       status as last_status,
       max(date_updated) filter (where status = 'published') over (partition by component_id) as last_published 
from components
order by component_id, last_updated desc;
```

Comment: Thanks @gordon-linoff, I edited my question slightly, I need the publish status as well, how would i tweak your sql to add this?

Comment: I added this line

**(array_agg(status order by date_updated) filter (where status = 'published'))[1]  as last_pub_status**

Comment: @Dale . . . I don't understand the "published status", but there is a simpler way to get it.  I modified the first query.

Answer (score 0):

By useing over and partition by you could sort by component_id and get the latest values per component id based on date and then join in the latest publish date based on that status.

Example:

```
with last_status as
(
SELECT 
  component_id
  , date_updated
  , status
  , row_number() over (partition by component_id order by date_updated desc) as R
  FROM test_data
),

last_publish as 
(
SELECT 
  component_id
  , max(date_updated) as last_published
FROM test_data
where upper(status) = 'PUBLISH'
GROUP BY component_id
)

select 
  last_status.* 
  , last_publish.last_published
from last_status 
left join last_publish on last_publish.component_id = last_status.component_id
where last_status.R = 1
```